# error: ‘glDeleteBuffers’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: opengl, love2d

Estoy teniendo problemas al compilar [Löve 0.7.2](https://github.com/love2d/love/releases/tag/0.7.2) sobre `Linux Mint 20 Ulyana` con base `Ubuntu 20.04 focal`, esta versión de Löve es vieja, pero un juego llamado [Not Pacman](https://stabyourself.net/notpacman/) la requiere.

He intentado lo más que puedo sin lograr resultados, el error se produce en el archivo SpriteBatch.cpp. Intente hacer esto (uno a la vez):

```cpp
void glDeleteBuffers(GLsizei n, const GLuint *buffers);
```

```cpp
void fp_glDeleteBuffersE(GLsizei n, const GLuint *buffers);
```

```cpp
void _glDeleteBuffers(GLsizei n, const GLuint *buffers);
```

Es decir, agregar las definiciones de todas las funciones que dice no estar declaradas y funciona, compila, pero obtengo un error al final del proceso (lo mismo para los otros casos):

```cpp
undefined reference to `glDeleteBuffers(int, unsigned int const*)'
```

Ya no sé qué más hacer, llevo varias horas intentando que compile. Espero que alguien pasara en algún momento por algo parecido y me pueda dar una mano para solucionar esto.

---

###### ¿Qué fue lo que hice?

1. Descargué [Löve](https://github.com/love2d/love/releases/download/0.7.2/love-0.7.2-linux-src.tar.gz) desde GitHub
2. Extraje el contenido del archivo (clic derecho -> Extraer Aquí)
3. Abrí una Terminal y cambié de directorio: `cd love-HEAD/`
4. Instalé las dependencias: `sudo apt-get install build-essential automake libmpg123-dev libmodplug-dev libphysfs-dev libfreetype-dev libdevil-dev libluajit-5.1-dev libopenal-dev libsdl1.2-dev libvorbis-dev libmng-dev`
5. Ejecuté `configure` de esta manera: `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-luajit`

   - Si obtiene el error `lua.h: No such file or directory` deberá modificar el archivo `configure`, en mi caso cambié la línea **15257** `INCLUDE_LUA` de `luajit-2.0` a `luajit-2.1`
6. Ejecuté `make`

   - Si obtiene el error `unknown type name ‘luaL_reg’` deberá reemplazar `luaL_reg` por `luaL_Reg`
     donde corresponda en `src/libraries/luasocket/libluasocket/`

---

Gracias.

Comment: Seguí tus pasos y obtuve un error para incluir `lua.h`.

Comment: @Mateo: Una disculpa, creo que ya esta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Actualización:

Una manera más rápida de «corregir» estos errores es modificar el archivo `GLee.h`. Por ejemplo, para `glDeleteBuffers` será necesario agregar esto:

```
#ifdef GL_VERSION_1_5
#undef GL_VERSION_1_5
#endif
```

¿Dónde? Yo lo coloqué debajo de `/* GL_VERSION_1_5 */` en la línea **1550**. Para esta versión de Löve los demás cambios son los siguientes:

```
#ifdef GL_ARB_framebuffer_object
#undef GL_ARB_framebuffer_object
#endif
```

*Debajo de* `/* GL_ARB_framebuffer_object */`

```
#ifdef GL_EXT_framebuffer_object
#undef GL_EXT_framebuffer_object
#endif
```

*Debajo de* `/* GL_EXT_framebuffer_object */`

Aún sigo sin entender el origen de estos errores, pero parece ser que la versión de [GLee](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/) es demasiado vieja y se «rompió» la compatibilidad con lo que se ofrece en las distribuciones modernas.

---

Despues de investigar y examinar los archivos fuente del proyecto me di cuenta de que me faltaba agregar lo siguiente:

```cpp
typedef void (APIENTRYP GLEEPFNGLDELETEBUFFERSPROC) (GLsizei  n, const GLuint * buffers);
GLEEPFNGLDELETEBUFFERSPROC GLeeFuncPtr_glDeleteBuffers;
#define glDeleteBuffers GLeeFuncPtr_glDeleteBuffers
```

Y seria lo mismo para las otras funciones faltantes, por ejemplo para `glGenBuffers`:

```cpp
typedef void (APIENTRYP GLEEPFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC) (GLsizei  n, GLuint * buffers);
GLEEPFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC GLeeFuncPtr_glGenBuffers;
#define glGenBuffers GLeeFuncPtr_glGenBuffers
```

Este sería el patrón:

**Función**: `glBindBuffer`
**FunciónM**: `GLBINDBUFFER`
**[Argumentos](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/)**: `GLenum  target, GLuint  buffer`

`typedef void (APIENTRYP GLEEPFN`***FunciónM***`PROC) (`***Argumentos***`);`
`GLEEPFN`***FunciónM***`PROC GLeeFuncPtr_`***Función***`;`
`#define` ***Función*** `GLeeFuncPtr_`***Función***

El proyecto compila y se ejecuta correctamente (hasta donde he probado). Por desgracia no termino de entender estos errores y porque hay que hacer esto manualmente, pero funciona.

Comment: Es extraño porque en el código existen las instrucciones que debería haber. [1](https://github.com/love2d/love/blob/0.7.2/src/modules/graphics/opengl/GLee.h#L1653), [2](https://github.com/love2d/love/blob/0.7.2/src/modules/graphics/opengl/GLee.h#L1634), [3](https://github.com/love2d/love/blob/0.7.2/src/modules/graphics/opengl/GLee.h#L1615). Parece un problema que no se puede reproducir. Si describieras los pasos que seguiste para compilarlo tal vez podríamos llegar a la causa.

Comment: @Mateo: Ya agregué los pasos que seguí, por desgracia, nada fuera de lo normal.